# Setting Up Multiple Actions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if it was possible to have more than 1 action in the link. For example, If I wanted to have multiple links such as:

http://www.mywebsite.com/(CONTROLLER)/(ID)/(ACTION)

[http://]www.mywebsite.com/user/Micheal/EditMovies
[http://]www.mywebsite.com/user/Micheal/EditFavorites

Is there some sort of way to do this? If not, do I have to specify multiple id's in the function and then use a case to determine which page they are going to be sent to?

In my UserController.cs I have:

```
public ActionResult Index(string username)
    {
        if (username != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var userid = (Membership.GetUser(username, false).ProviderUserKey);
                Users user = entity.User.Find(userid);
                return View(user);   
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("", "Home");
    }
```

In my Routes I have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "User",
            url: "User/{username}",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Index" }
        );
```

What I'm trying to make it do is have additional functions for second actions so I can do something like:

```
User/{username}/{actionsAdditional}
```

And In my UserController I can put more actions which will leader to the second action actionsAdditional

```
public ActionResult Index(string username)
    {
        if (username != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var userid = (Membership.GetUser(username, false).ProviderUserKey);
                Users user = entity.User.Find(userid);
                return View(user);   
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("", "Home");
    }

public ActionResult EditFavorites()
    {
```

//DoStuff
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this multiple ways, here's just one:

Set up a route to handle this:

```
routes.MapRoute("UserEditsThings",
    "user/{id}/edit/{thingToEdit}",
    new { controller = "UserController", action="Edit" },
    new { thingToEdit = ValidThingsToEditConstraint() }
);
```

Then your action in the `User` Controller should look like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(ThingToEdit thingToEdit) {
    ThingToEditViewModel viewModel = new ThingToEditViewModel(thingToEdit);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The `RouteConstraint` is what would take their input (the thingToEdit) and make sure it was valid (you could do this in a few places - like in a Custom ModelBinder):

```
public class ValidThingsToEditConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        //simplistic implementation simply to show what's possible.
        return values['thingToEdit'] == "Favorites" || values['thingToEdit'] == "Movies";

    }
}
```

Now, that way, you can have one method to Edit both Movies and Favorites, and you simply add a parameter to show what 'type' of thing they're editing.

If you wanted to keep your current route, you should be able to do the following:

```
routes.MapRoute("UserEditsThings",
    "user/{id}/edit{thingToEdit}",
    new { controller = "UserController", action="Edit" },
    new { thingToEdit = ValidThingsToEditConstraint() }
);
```

I've been away from ASP.NET MVC for about 7 months, so this could be a little rusty. It has not been tested for syntax errors and bits of python may shine through.  It should get you there, though.

Comment: I tried to get this working, but couldnt. Let me try to specify what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to make it where First there's a User Controller and takes in an id of username and the action is set on /Index/ as the default in the routeconfig to get rid of it in the link. I wanted to make it where they can go /User/Micheal/Edit/Favoites where I'm able to make a Favorites ActionResult in the UserController along with the Index actionresult which takes in a string username.

Comment: Your best bet is to edit the routes you have and the controller setup you want into your question. I have to say I don't understand the prose, but may understand the code if you post it.